# How to completely uninstall Minikube in windows 10 Pro? (chocolatey)

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I came to the realization that Windows 10 Docker has the Kubernetes options in it now, so I want to completely uninstall minikube and use the Kubernetes version that comes with docker windows instead.

How can I completely uninstall minikube in windows 10?

Comment: Thank you downvoter for no explanation

Comment: No idea why it would get downvoted. Maybe your question was too trivial to 'very smart' people.

Comment: Why do you need to completely uninstall minikube? You could just delete minikube vm and start minikube with `minikube start --driver=docker`. Remember to launch docker desktop first!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This as simple as running:

```
minikube stop & REM stops the VM

minikube delete & REM deleted the VM
```

Then delete the `.minikube` and `.kube` directories usually under:

```
C:\users\{user}\.minikube
```

and

```
C:\users\{user}\.kube
```

Or if you are using chocolatey:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\minikube stop
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\minikube delete
choco uninstall minikube
choco uninstall kubectl
```

Comment: Just to extend, for osx or *nix users, same minikube commands and `rm $HOME/.minikube` and `rm $HOME/.kube`.

Comment: @Rico when I do where `minikube` , I get `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\minikube.exe` , as I used choclatey to download and install it.Can you kindly extend your answer so it includes those who installed minikube using chocolatey ? thanks

Comment: @murarisumit please free to add this to the answer so it helps users from all platforms

Comment: @Matthew added to the answer. Thx!

Comment: @Rico looks like this also works ´choco uninstall minikube´ and ´choco uninstall kubectl´

Comment: @Rico I was able to uninstall minikube and kubectl by using the commands you provide. However, I cannot remove the machines since they are 'Device or resource busy'. I have tried to umount them by using the command 'umount ~/.minikube' but I have got 'Invalid argument'. Any ideas how to go?

Comment: @Joe you have to provide the full path to `umount`

Comment: @Rico even with full path: /c/Users/myusername/.minikube
I am still getting the same message:
umount: /c/Users/myusername/.minikube: Invalid argument
Any ideas of why could this be happening?

Comment: @Joe sounds like you may be using mount for windows that has different options. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mount

Comment: @Rico I wonder if your last command is unnecessary as `minikube uninstall` already removed it? `PS C:\ProgramData> choco uninstall kubectl
Chocolatey v1.1.0
Uninstalling the following packages:
kubectl
kubectl is not installed. Cannot uninstall a non-existent package.
`

Comment: For anyone like me who installed minikube but already used kubectl pointing to remote clusters: beware that deleting `C:\users\{user}\.kube`, you may accidentally remove other clusters' kube config files! In my case I will just remove config-minikube inside that folder