# How do I change the location of .minikube folder?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

How do I change the location of the entire `.minikube` folder that gets created when you run minikube? (Windows 10 system using Hyper-V)

```
C:\Users\username\.minikube
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the most painless method will be

1. [Remove minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271159/9929015)
2. change minikube install location with `MINIKUBE_HOME` var

   set MINIKUBE_HOME=D:\Uerotavlas.minikube
3. start cluster again

Answer (score 1):

Setting MINIKUBE_HOME in terminal might not work, and this variable will be temporary and forgotten when the terminal is closed. Instead, add a System environment variable called MINIKUBE_HOME in Windows by opening Run->sysdm.cpl->Advanced->Environment Variables and set its value to the custom folder you dedicated to Minikube. For example D:.minikube

Delete existing Minikube cluster, if any, using this command:

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
```

Close existing terminal you have open, if any, and open it again.
Run `minikube start` and it will pick up the new location for Minikube.
[image: Minikube start message]

*Thanks for @Vit for introducing me to the MINIKUBE_HOME environment variable*

Comment: `export MINIKUBE_HOME=/new/path` is enough