# How to start/run minikube containers on Non-OS drive

Tags: installation, minikube, vmware-workstation

I am running a minikube cluster using vmware driver on Windows 7 with Vmware Workstation v15.x.x.

```
PS C:\Users\adminuser> minikube.exe config view
- WantUpdateNotification: false
- driver: vmware
- profile: k8-home-cluster

PS C:\Users\adminuser> minikube.exe start --cpus=4 --memory=4096 --nodes=2
* [k8-home-cluster] minikube v1.28.0 on Microsoft Windows XXXXXX
* Using the vmware driver based on user configuration
* Starting control plane node k8-home-cluster in cluster k8-home-cluster
* Creating vmware VM (CPUs=4, Memory=4096MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.25.3 on Docker 20.10.20 ...
  - Generating certificates and keys ...
  - Booting up control plane ...
  - Configuring RBAC rules ...
```

This starts 2 x VMs under **C:\Users\adminuser\.minikube** folder

```
PS C:\Users\adminuser\.minikube\machines> dir

    Directory: C:\Users\adminuser\.minikube\machines

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         21-May-23   8:49 PM            k8-home-cluster
d----         21-May-23   8:49 PM            k8-home-cluster-m02
d----         21-May-23   8:07 PM            minikube
```

Can the cluster nodes be started on a Non-OS Data Drive? I have specific Data Drives for VMWare Workstation.

Should I reinstall minikube on one of those specific drives to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution from these:

1. [How do I change the location of .minikube folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775701/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-minikube-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [How do I change the location of .minikube folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775701/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-minikube-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/

This is what I did:

1. Minikube Stop + Delete (Stop the current Minikube setup running in C: and then delete all it's references.)

```
minikube stop

minikube delete
```

Optional : I reboot the system.

2. Create a new **System variables** called MINIKUBE_HOME in Windows

   - Run(Windows + R) > sysdm.cpl > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables
   - Set its value to the Folder Path to be used for Minikube nodes (For e.g. G:\K8s)

- 

3. Start Minikube with the required flags and the minikube setup should start running from the new location.

```
PS G:\K8s> minikube.exe config view
- WantUpdateNotification: false
- driver: vmware
- profile: k8-home-cluster
PS G:\K8s>
PS G:\K8s>
PS G:\K8s> minikube.exe start --nodes=2 --cpus=4 --memory=4096
* [k8-home-cluster] minikube v1.28.0 on Microsoft Windows XXXXXX
  - MINIKUBE_HOME=G:\K8s  ## This is my dedicated folder for Minikube/Containers ##

* Using the vmware driver based on user configuration
* Starting control plane node k8-home-cluster in cluster k8-home-cluster
* Creating vmware VM (CPUs=4, Memory=4096MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
~
~
~
PS G:\K8s\.minikube\machines> dir

    Directory: G:\K8s\.minikube\machines

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         22-May-23   8:53 PM            k8-home-cluster
d----         22-May-23   8:53 PM            k8-home-cluster-m02
-a---         22-May-23   8:52 PM       1675 server-key.pem
-a---         22-May-23   8:52 PM       1237 server.pem
```

Hope this helps!