# WSL2 (Ubuntu) can't connect Kubernetes via kubectl that was installed in Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've installed Docker Desktop, Kubernetes, and Minikube on Windows. Now I'd like to use kubectrl on WSL2 (Ubuntu), but I don't know how.

If I run `kubectl version` and `kubectl cluster-info` on Windows (PowerShell):

```
PS C:\Users\UserName> kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.3
```

```
PS C:\Users\UserName> kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:49366
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:49366/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

If I run them on WSL2:

```
user@LAPTOP:~/app$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

```
user@LAPTOP:~/app$ kubectl cluster-info
E0207 06:34:05.061042   29276 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0207 06:34:05.061283   29276 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0207 06:34:05.062630   29276 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0207 06:34:05.062815   29276 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0207 06:34:05.064124   29276 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

It seems to me that Kubectrl uses port `49366` on Windows but it uses port `8080`. Is it the cause? If so, how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**
I added the following line in `~/.bashrc` on WSL2 and then ran `source ~/.bashrc`:

`export KUBECONFIG=/mnt/c/users/UserName/.kube/config`

Now I see the following:

```
user@LAPTOP:~/app$ kubectl cluster-info
Error in configuration: 
* unable to read client-cert /mnt/c/users/UserName/.kube/C:\Users\UserName\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt for minikube due to open /mnt/c/users/UserName/.kube/C:\Users\UserName\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt: no such file or directory
```

It seems that kubectl on WSL2 can't access minikube on Windows

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu, thanks for your message. I've just replied to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, I installed Kubernetes and Minikube on Window. This was wrong. What I had to do was to install them on WSL2 only. After Minikibe was removed by following [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271159/3655192) and Minikune was installed into wsl2, Minikube and kubectl commands started to work on wsl2

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue ensure that the kubectl configuration file on WSL2 is pointing to the correct location of the Minikube configuration. It happens due to the KUBECONFIG environment variable not set. Either the relevant user is not configured to use kubectl, or the.kube/config file is missing.

Also verify that WSL2 has the KUBECONFIG environment variable set. If not, direct it to the appropriate configuration file that has cluster information. Generally under your Windows user directory in.kube/config.

**As per the official kubernetes doc on [Creating a cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information), Try the below commands to resolve your issu**e :

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
kubectl get nodes
```

Also follow this [blog](https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/the-connection-to-the-server-localhost8080-was-refused/) by K21 Academy to resolve the  error you're getting.

**Follow below troubleshooting steps to resolve the error** :

**1.** First make sure that the windows and WSL2 firewall rules permit port communication. Check portfording is properly set up or different ports are used by kubectl on Windows and WSL2. Use Proxy server which helps  to resolve any network-related issues that may be preventing the connection.

**2.** Try using minikube start embed-certs to launch the minikube.

**3.** Logs will make this quite evident no such file or directory. Please see Unable to read client-cert/key for additional information and solutions.

**4.** Verify the client's file location and check. The crt file is present in the designated location in your WSL2 distribution. To view the directory's contents in WSL2, use the 1s command.

**5.** Check kubectl versions compatibility on both Windows and WSL2.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such folder as `/etc/kubernetes` in wsl2, so I'm not sure `sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config` will do anything. Also, I don't need `kubeadm` (for now).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is connected with the certificate that minikube uses to connect. It prob stored on windows.
Did you tehy to symbolic link it?

example:
ln -s /mnt/c/users/Hiroki/.kube/C:\Users\Takahashi.minikube/ /home/user/.kube/minikube

and try the connection.

Or try the firewall of the wsl2 if it blocks some ports.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you got:

> unable to read client-cert /mnt/c/users/UserName/.kube/C:\Users\UserName.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt for minikube due to open /mnt/c/users/UserName/.kube/C:\Users\UserName.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt: no such file or directory

I had a similar error and managed to fix it.

You set your `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to the path of the Windows copy of your `.kube/config` file.
However, that `config` file (located in `C:\Users\UserName\.kube\`) contains some Windows paths to certificate and private key files.

One such file is mentioned in the error message:

```
C:\Users\UserName\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt
```

I found 3 such paths in my `config` file.

In order for Ubuntu to succeed in reading all these files, I copied `C:\Users\UserName\.kube\config` to The Ubuntu user's home dir (`/home/username/.kube/`) and edited the invalid paths to valid Unix paths.

For example, I changed:

```
C:\Users\UserName\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt
```

to:

```
/mnt/c/users/UserName/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
```

After making these changes, you don't need the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable. `kubectl` on Ubuntu will use `/home/username/.kube/config`.

I realize this is not an ideal solution, since it forces you to maintain two versions of `.kube/config`. Perhaps there's a way to modify the original `config` file to be readable by both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. By following your solution, I can use kubectl on wsl2, but I still can't use minikube. Do I need to install minikube on wsl2 too? (I already have it on windows)

Comment: @Hiroki I did not have to install minikube on wsl2. I only installed it on Windows. What errors are you getting now? What do you see when you run `kubectl config get-contexts`?